# Скопировать таблицу из Access в MS SQL через C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, access, ado.net

Есть Access база и нужно взять и перенести ее целиком с данными в MS SQL.

Можно конечно, копировать по строчно через DataReader одиночными вставками, но это медленно.

В память я так же не хочу целиком грузить DataTable из Access.

Как это сделать максимально быстро?

Comment: " но это медленно" - вы храните в Access столь большие таблицы, что так важна скорость?

Comment: какой размер таблицы? сколько Гб? Если помещается в память, то очень быстро можно перегнать через DataTable с помощью BulkCopy. Займет от 7 сек до 5 мин на все, в зависимости от объема данных и загруженности целевой БД. На крайний случай импорт данных в файл и BULK INSERT, который этот файл импортирует напрямую в БД. Это можно сделать вообще без шарпа. Формат файла данных смотри в описании команды BULK INSERT

Comment: @rdom, по идее, BulkCopy подойдет. Одна из перегрузок WriteToServer принимает на вход DataReader источника. Он все равно сливает все данные из источника в память(DataTable) или напрямую загружает на сервер сохраняя высокую скорость?

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно просто перекачать данные, и нужно делать это именно через C#, то прибегать к использованию `DataTable` необязательно.

Потоковая загрузка данных в SqlServer делается с помощью `SqlBulkCopy`, потоковое чтение из Access - с помощью `OleDbDataReader`.

`SqlBulkCopy` может принимать на вход не только `DataRow[]` и `DataTable`, но также `DbDataReader` и `IDataReader`. Т.к. `OleDbDataReader` является и тем и другим, то достаточно просто подать `OleDbDataReader` на вход метода `WriteToServer(...)` экземпляра `SqlBulkCopy`:

```cs
SqlConnection sqlConnection = ...;
OleDbConnection oledbConnection = ...;

using (var oledbCmd = new OleDbCommand(@"
    select Column1, Column2, ...
    from Table_Name", oledbConnection))
using (var oledbReader = oledbCmd.ExecuteReader())
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TableName";
    bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(oledbReader);
}
```

Целевая таблица перед этим, естественно, должна быть создана.

---

Другой вариант - обойтись без C#, средствами сугубо SqlServer-а. Для этого потребуется установить драйвер СУБД Access там же, где установлен инстанс SqlServer и настроить его использование.

Затем с помощью конструкции `OPENROWSET` можно обратиться к файлу БД Access и заимпортировать данные из выбранной таблицы командой `SELECT ... INTO` (или `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, если целевая таблица уже создана):

```sql
SELECT t.Column1, t.Column2, ...
INTO dbo.TableName
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'N:\AccessDbFiles\MsAccessDatabaseFile.accdb';
    'admin';'',
    [Table_Name]) AS t
```

Либо через *linked-server*. Подсоединяем Access-базу:

```sql
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
    @server = 'AccessDbName', -- алиас
    @srvproduct = 'Access',
    @provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    @datasrc = 'N:\AccessDbFiles\MsAccessDatabaseFile.accdb'
```

затем перекачиваем данные в нужную таблицу:

```sql
SELECT t.Column1, t.Column2, ...
INTO dbo.TableName
FROM [AccessDbName]...[Table_Name] AS t
```

Три точки в `[AccessDbName]...[AccessDb_Table_Name]` - это так и должно быть (*four-part naming*, где не указаны каталог и схема).

Обратите внимание, что в данном случае путь к файлу БД Access (`N:\AccessDbFiles\MsAccessDatabaseFile.accdb` в примерах) - это путь в координатах инстанса SqlServer (путь может быть сетевым), а не в координатах того хоста, с которого к нему подключаются.

Comment: для первого варианта критично, что вставляемая таблица и целевая могут различаться по структуре? Например, целевая имеет аналогичные типы, но имеет дополнительные атрибуты, которых нет во вставляемой таблице. Нормально все замапится, а недостающие колонки заполнятся NULLами?

Comment: @iluxa1810, если отличается количество столбцов, или порядок их следования, то, согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings.aspx), необходимо задавать mapping столбцов (`bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(...)` - там есть варианты name-to-name, name-to-index, index-to-name, index-to-index). Недостающие - да, должны NULL-ами заполняться.

Comment: хм, а про DataReader я как то забыл... спасибо что напомнили.